# FInd element on page

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, autotest

I have a [this page](https://qna.habr.com/q/157943),

On page is elements share (left-down on post):

```html
<button class="btn btn_share" role="dropdown_trigger" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" title=" Поделиться вопросом" aria-expanded="false">
  <svg class="icon_svg icon_sharing" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <use href="5e6a141a/images/sprite.svg#icon_sharing"></use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Tried using [tags:xpath],

```java
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath=//div[@class='btn btn_share']/div/div[5]/div/button"));

if (elements == null) {
    System.out.println("sharing no found");
    System.exit(1);
} else {
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

and using class select.

```java
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElementsByClassName("btn_share");

if (elements == null) {
    System.out.println("sharing no found");
    System.exit(1);
} else {
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        element.click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(50);
    }
}
```

But no any result.

How can I select one element and click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find elements `By.cssSelector` with this value : `[class*='btn_share']`.

And for the validation you can use `elements.size()==0` not `elements == null`.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class*='btn_share']"));

if(elements.size()==0) {
    System.out.println("sharing no found");
}else {
    for(WebElement element: elements) {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)